# show only top 2 values in group

Tags: mysql, sql

The current code I have finds the average and shows all 4. I am trying to trim it down to holy show the information for the top 2 highest average,

```
SELECT BRANCHSUBURB, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM BRANCH NATURAL JOIN SESSIONS 
GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
ORDER BY BRANCHSUBURB;
```

i.e should only show manly and cronulla
click image
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aROxd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT BRANCHSUBURB, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM BRANCH NATURAL JOIN SESSIONS 
GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Note:  I strongly advise you not to use `NATURAL JOIN`.  In my opinion, it is a bug waiting to happen.  The `NATURAL JOIN` works based on any columns that have the same names in the two tables -- it doesn't even use *declared* foreign key relationships.  It is much better to use a regular join with a `USING` clause.

Comment: I keep getting "SQL command not properly ended" when trying this, what could be the issue here?

Comment: How would I achieve the same thing using ROWNUM?

Comment: @Dan . . . First, you would install Oracle.  Your question is tagged MySQL.  If you have a question about Oracle, then ask another question, with the appropriate tag.